# Emulating mobile in ChromeDriver

Tags: mobile, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

If you're using WebDriver with Chrome (via Chromedriver) you may want to emulate mobile viewport characteristics. Similarly, you may want to automate tests on desktop without having to use a proper Chrome on Android setup.

How do you do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `mobile_emulation` capability was added to ChromeDriver in 2.11

Full documentation: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation

My notes below:

Creating a driver in Python with the mobile_emulation capability options:

```
 driver = self.CreateDriver(
        mobile_emulation = {
            'deviceMetrics': {'width': 360, 'height': 640, 'pixelRatio': 3}})
```

Currently you can emulate devicepixelratio, useragent, viewport height and width.

[Possible properties](https://codereview.chromium.org/288193004/patch/1/10002#newcode104) for the mobile_emulation dict:

- `deviceName` : if used, must be the only property. Matches a [device preset](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/toolbox/OverridesUI.js&q=WebInspector.OverridesUI._phones%20file:OverridesUI.js&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=310) in Chrome (e.g. `'Google Nexus 5'`).
- `deviceMetrics`: a dict that can include width (int), height (int), pixelRatio (double) as shown above.
- `userAgent`: a string to spoof at the request header and navigator object.

Comment: The link to the valid device names should probably be fixed? https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/emulated_devices/module.json&sq=package:chromium&type=cs

Answer (score 7):

This is in the latest official chromedriver build ([2.11](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.11/notes.txt)).

Example in java:

```
final DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
dc.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, new ChromeOptions() {
{
    setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", new HashMap<String, Object>() {
            {
                put("deviceName", "Google Nexus 5");
            }
        });
    }
});

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(dc);
```

Answer (score 6):

The mobileEmulation option is implemented in the last ChromeDriver release (v 2.11). Using WebDriverJs you have to add it as property to the capabilities object.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var capabilities = {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
    mobileEmulation: {
      deviceName: 'Apple iPhone 5'
    }
  }
};
var
  driver = new webdriver
  .Builder()
  .withCapabilities(capabilities)
  .build();


driver.get('http://google.com');

var bool = false;
setTimeout(function () {
  bool = true;
}, 9000);
driver.wait(function() {
 return bool;
}, 10000);

driver.quit();
```

Comment: thanks! this is useful as official docs dont provide info for webdriver JS

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to use mobile emulation in Chrome. Providing `'deviceName'` or device `'height', 'width', 'pixelRatio'` at the `'setExperimentalOption'` method of `ChromeOptions`. Explained details in this [video](https://youtu.be/UOwEcGr3P9A).